# Facebook Like box and Like buttons return Error

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I'm integrating FB social plugins - Like box and Like buttons (as iframes) - on a web page, but they don't work.

When I click on Like in "Like box", I get "Error" text with link, which displays a message dialog "The page at https://www.facebook.com/provocateur.eu could not be reached.".

JSON response is:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"Website Inaccessible","full":"The page at https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/provocateur.eu could not be reached.","errorUri":"\/connect\/connect_to_node_error.php?title=Website+Inaccessible&body=The+page+at+https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.facebook.com\u00252Fprovocateur.eu+could+not+be+reached.&hash=AQARp73z7huT0Eiu"}}}
```

When I click on the Like button, the JSON response is:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"An error occurred.","full":"There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/tools\/lint\/) and fixing any errors.","errorUri":"\/connect\/connect_to_node_error.php?title=An+error+occurred.&body=There+was+an+error+liking+the+page.+If+you+are+the+page+owner\u00252C+please+try+running+your+page+through+the+linter+on+the+Facebook+devsite+\u002528https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fdevelopers.facebook.com\u00252Ftools\u00252Flint\u00252F\u002529+and+fixing+any+errors.&hash=AQAFI_8ieMUGPPxS"}}}
```

This is the "Like box" iframe code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:240px; height:70px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprovocateur.eu&width=240&height=70&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=false&border_color&stream=false&header=true&appId=283499041689204"></iframe>
```

and this is the "Like button" iframe code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:203px; height:21px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=203&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21&amp;appId=283499041689204"></iframe>
```

The behaviour is the same for admin and non-admin visitors and for any browser. I created application with the same name as FB page with appId 283499041689204. Web page is XHTML transitional valid, and it contains no errors according FB debugger/linter. Formely there was age restriction (17+), but I removed it and for the moment it is accessible for anyone (13+).

URL of web page: http://provocateur.eu/

URL of FB page: in the first error message

Any help appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link may be NSFW if you work somewhere conservative BTW.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem! I see your site is working well now, did you find a solution for this? extra info:
if I go to the API explorer (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes) the website is not listed as being one of my likes, **BUT** when I go to the FQL test site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) and put the code "SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id=MY_USER_ID" it shows a link to the website. Tkx

Comment: Hi! The problem with Like box (on my site bottom left) was fixed as bug by Facebook and the problem with Like button I fixed by setting "href" URL parameter of Like button to exact URL instead of leaving empty. I hope it will help you. Good luck!